# Incorrect Rendering of Table Columns from JSON Data

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I have the following JSON structure:

```
{"rows": [

      {"row":[  
             {"cells": [
                   {"data": "Edit"},
                   {"data": "Add"}
             ]}
      ]},
      {"row":[
             {"cells": [
                   {"data": 1},
                   {"data": 2}
             ]}
      ]}
]}
```

For every "row" in the JSON file, there will be a table row and for every "data" a row column.

My code looks like this:

```
$.each(response.rows, function(index, rows){

     $.each(rows.row, function(index, row){
          $("tbody").append("<tr>"); 
          $.each(this.cells, function(){ 
               $("tr").append("<td>" + this.data + "</td>");
          });
          $("tbody").append("</tr>");
     });
});
```

My code is generating the table rows/columns like this:

```
Row 1 -- I get 4 columns with values "Edit"/"Add"/1/2 
Row 2 -- I get 2 columns with values 1/2.
```

If I add another "row" in JSON file, then Row 1 & 2 are rendered incorrectly.

Row 1 should only have 2 columns with values "Edit"/"Add". The JSON structure seems right.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your syntax: http://jsfiddle.net/SXzny/ That fixes it, because it doesn't reference all  tags, but the one you created.

For example, replace:

```
$.each(rows.row, function(index, row){
  $("tbody").append("<tr>"); 
  $.each(this.cells, function(){ 
       $("tr").append("<td>" + this.data + "</td>");
  });
  $("tbody").append("</tr>");
});
```

with:

```
$.each(rows.row, function(index, row){
  var element = $("tbody").append("<tr>"); 
  $.each(this.cells, function(){ 
       element.append("<td>" + this.data + "</td>");
  });
  $("tbody").append("</tr>");
});
```

Comment: I didn't catch the syntax error. I compared both and everything looks the same except for this line - $.each(response.rows, function(index, rows)...???

Comment: Sorry, syntax is not the correct term... I'll update my answer

Comment: This works like a charm!!

So, if I understand it, I was referring to all the rows created while element.append make a reference to the corresponding "row" of the "cells" being looped. 

Did I get this right?

Comment: Correct. `$('div')` is all DIVs in the DOM, same goes for any other HTML tag. So an action you apply to `$(TAG_NAME)` will be applied to all those tags.